# UIActivityViewController using multiple arrays

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am creating a multiple array ActivityItem and it ends up showing no sharing options.

I have a list of strings and a single image that need to be shared and I do not get an error but I do not get options for mail or message.  Yes I am using a phone and not a simulator.

```
let shareSheet = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [getActivityItems(array), shareImage()], applicationActivities: nil)

func getActivityItems(_ array: Array) -> [String] {

return  ["Stuff:\t\t(stuff)",
        "Stuff:\t\t(stuff)",
        "Stuff:\t\t(stuff)"]
```

How would like to be able to use my array of strings and add an image to share at the same time.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: For one thing, as written, the array you are returning from `getActivityItems` is incorrect. The leading parenthesis of your last two items should be inside the leading quotations of the last two items, respectively.

Comment: I have tried to convert to string with getActivityItems return "String:\t\t(array.string)" +  The problem with this is there are 7 items and after the sixth I get expression was too complex to be solved.  So converting the array to string is not an option.

Comment: Is there a way to combine two functions?  A func that produces strings and a func that produces a image?  Then produce a final func that holds both funcs so that I can call the single func instead of two separate ones?